# Move a rotating cube on mousedown with CSS and Jquery

Tags: jquery, css, css-transforms

I am trying to create a rotating cube that can be moved around by the user to the particular side they want by clicking on the cube and dragging it. I currently have something that moves when the **mouse moves** around the screen but this makes it hard to control which side you want, plus you can't stop the cube rotating.

Please see this codepen for an example of what I have: https://codepen.io/ryan_pixelers/pen/kkVErB

**jquery code that makes the cube rotate**

```
$(function(){
  $(window).mousemove(function(e){
    $('.cube').css('transform', 'rotateX(' + - e.pageY + 'deg)' +     'rotateY(' + e.pageX + 'deg)');
  }); 
})
```

I need this kind of smooth movement, but only when the mouse is clicked. **Mousedown doesn't work**.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you can try `transition: 0.9s all linear` for smooth scrolling on `.cube`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I answered the question myself, right after asking it:

updated jquery:

```
$(function(){
  $(window).mousedown(function(){
  $(window).mousemove(function(e){
      $('.cube').css('transform', 'rotateX(' + - e.pageY + 'deg)' + 'rotateY(' + e.pageX + 'deg)');
  });

  $(window).mouseup(function(){
    $(this).off( "mousemove" );
  });

  }); 
})
```